# import user-defined Defaults Odoo

Tags: odoo

Today I tried to import some configuration from one data base of Odoo to another (User-defined Defaults) and everything looks ok, but the default values that i'm trying to insert to my new data base (for many2many fields) don't work. I believed it was by for the csv file and i try to add using  xml record like this:

```
    <record id="hr_test_record" model="ir.values">
        <field name="value_unpickle">2</field>
        <field name="name">struct_id</field>
        <field name="model">hr.contract</field>
        <field name="key">default</field>
        <field name="value">I2 .</field>
    </record>
```

but in the database space (for value)  appears this way after install the module

### value

S'2' +
 p0   +
 .

And has to look like this

### value

I2   +
 .

I know this but how can apply this?
I is for Integer
S is for string
V is for value

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am having the a similar problem. For some reason I can not figure out how to add a `ir.values` record via XML data file. Did you have any luck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To store the value as integer, you must use XML notation to encode the \n character (result of pickle.dumps operation) and must not specify a value for the field "value_unpickle".

e.g.

```
<record id="hr_test_record" model="ir.values">    
        <field name="name">struct_id</field>
        <field name="model">hr.contract</field>
        <field name="key">default</field>
        <field name="key2"/>
        <field name="value">I2&#10;.</field>
</record>
```

note that you also need to set key2 to empty string if you don't want any conditions/qualifiers for your default value.

(the above is tested in odoo 10)